# Can I find any free solution for storing my files online?

Tags: dropbox, google-drive-api, cloud-hosting, file-sharing

I am developing an application which needs to fetch some data from an XML file for the automatic update process and for some other functions. This approach requires the files to be located in a direct link, so it can be hard-programmed to use that specific URL.

I heard that you can use a lot of free-to-use file-sharing services such as **Google Drive**, **Box** and **Dropbox**. Can you tell me if it's true or not? And are there any other services beside those I mentioned?

I don't need a web hosting that supports PHP and other frameworks, I just want to store files and make my application access it when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both Dropbox and Google Drive provide web hosting of your public folders, but there is a 10GB bandwidth limit with Dropbox.
You can use any free web hosting like 110mb or 5gbfree too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try github, bitbucket or mega.co.nz